# DB values are not in global scope

Tags: python, database

#### Usage

I am using the [replit](https://replit.com/) browser IDE for this project. Also, I am using [replit's database](https://docs.replit.com/misc/database) for this project.

#### Problem

So as you can see, in the code below, I am asking the user to log in or Sign up, while saving the user's data of money, deposits, inventory in a key-value pair into the database of replit. It is simple to do that, first I import replit:

```py
from replit import db
```

And then I assign the key-value pairs to a list like:

```py
username = input("Enter new Username: ")
password = input("Enter new password: ")

db[username] = [password, 300000, [], 500, 0, False]
              # the password, money, inventory, allowed deposit, deposited, and boolean for working or not, respectively.
```

But to actually uses the user's stats saved to their value pair, I have to make the username available in all places in the code. Rather I assigned them to variables:

```py
self.money = db[username][1]
self.inventory = db[username][2]
self.deposit_allowed = db[username][3]
self.deposited = db[username][4]
self.working = db[username][5]
```

But despite doing that, I get errors that "user name is not defined" and "self.inventory is not defined". I am getting the values using the list as you will see below

#### The Real Question

My real question is that ***how*** can I make the variables, that I have put up, have the values of the list that I have assigned to the value pair of the user's name and make it work globally. Because later in the code, I append to the `self.inventory` list which is *in* the value pair list assigned to the user.

#### Code

Here is a portion of the important code that I am using.

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self, username):
        self.money = db[username][1]
        self.inventory = db[username][2]
        self.deposit_allowed = db[username][3]
        self.deposited = db[username][4]
        self.working = db[username][5]
        
    def database(self):
        enter_game = input("Do you want to [1] Login\n[2] Signup:\n>")
        while enter_game == '1' or enter_game == '2':
            if enter_game == '1':
                username = input("Enter user name: ")
                password = input("Enter password: ")

                if username in db.keys():
                    if db[username][0] == password:
                        print("Loggedd In")
                        break

                else: 
                    print("Invalid Username, Password")
                    break

            if enter_game == '2':
                username = input("Enter new Username: ")
                password = input("Enter new password: ")

                db[username] = [password, 300000, [], 500, 0, False]
                break
```

Also, the project is literally ***massive***, so rather, I have attached a link to go to the real code(The code that is used here is in the `gameplay.py` file):
[Click here](https://replit.com/@OldWizard209/Life-SIMULATOR-In-Development-2#gameplay.py) to go to the repl with the code.

Or if that doesn't work, click here:

https://replit.com/@OldWizard209/Life-SIMULATOR-In-Development-2#gameplay.py